# Implications for Google Tag Manager code snippet at the bottom of HTML just before closing </body> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

Are there any problems having the Google Tag Manager snippet at the bottom of the HTML page just before the closing  tag?

I see the developers guide says to put it at the top just after the opening  tag, but there shouldn't be any issue at the bottom, right?

Answer (score 1):

I have it installed there, and one issue is that Verifying your site in Web Master Tools via GTM may not work.

It's easy enough to use an old style meta tag in its place though.